# Laravel Eloquent group by with pivot table & relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have this platform I'm creating for foodtruck events. There is a pool of exhibitors who attend several events. Each foodtruck has it's own menu of dishes that they serve, in several categories.

**The problem / what I'd like to achieve**

> I would like to make a menu for each event, looping through all
>   exhibitors (who attend) and then showing the dishes by category.
>
> Something like this;
>
> /menu/{eventid}
>
> Dish category 1
>
> - dish from exhibitor A
> - dish from exhibitor B
>
> Dish category 2
>
> - dish from exh A
> - dish from exh C
> - dish from exh D
>
> ...

**Models**

Event model

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = "events";

    public function exhibitors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exhibitor', 'events_exhibitors');
    }
```

Dish model

```
class Dish extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = "dishes";    


    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function exhibitor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Exhibitor');
    }
}
```

Exhibitor model

```
class Exhibitor extends Model
{
    protected $table = "exhibitors";

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'events_exhibitors');
    }

    public function dishes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dish');
    }
}
```

**Database structure**

There is a pivot table to register which foodtrucks go to which events. So far, I think (hope) my relations are working. I hope this image shows enough;

[image: DB structure]

**What I've tried**

I've tried several things but I think my insight in Laravel eloquent lacks to understand the logic behind this issue.

```
$dishes = Event::where('id', $id)
            ->with(['exhibitors.dishes' => function($q) {
            $q->select('dishes.dish_data');
        }])->get();
```

Or

```
$dishes = Event::with(array('exhibitor.dish') => function($query) use ($sub){
            $query->where('name',$sub);}))->get();
```

I have absolutely no clue how to accomplish this by Eloquent or how this would work in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

It will get all the ids of the exhibitors that are connected to the event.
Then it will get all categories where the connected dishes have an exhibitor_id that is in the array of exhibitor ids.

Category Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = "categories";    


    public function dishes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dish', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Controller Action

```
$event = Event::findOrFail($id);

$exhibitorIds = $event->exhibitors()->select('exhibitors.id')->get()->pluck('id')->all();

$categories = Category::whereHas('dishes', function($query) use ($exhibitorIds) {
    $query->whereIn('exhibitor_id', $exhibitorIds);
})->with(['dishes' => function($query) use ($exhibitorIds) {
    $query->whereIn('exhibitor_id', $exhibitorIds);
}])->get();

return view('events.menu', compact('event', 'categories') );
```

View

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<h2>{{ $category->name }}</h2>
<ul>
   @foreach($category->dishes as $dish)
       <li>{{ $dish->dish_data }}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This throws an builder error "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given" at "$categories..."

Comment: Ok the exhibitorids where a Laravel collection, with ->all() it now returns an array. And the seconds query didn't use the exhibitorids

Comment: Still throws the same error... "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given". When I dd($exhibitorIds) it is indeed an array containing the id's.

Comment: Try it without the ->with(...)

Comment: Returns a collection with 3 items of type Category

Comment: OK I see in the docs I forgot to set the with statement with a function in an array. I edited the answer.

Comment: Try again now, the in the with statement, the function should be the value and the relation string the key.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: Downvoted. Might work, but use a profiler to profile the generated SQL queries (queries, as you are hitting the db multiple times) generated for such an easy requirement.

While this might achieve the OP's requirement, this is far from a good example on how to use the Laravel Eloquent ORM for this use case..

Comment: Check the relations between the models. You always need to go over multiple relations to get the correct models. Laravel doesn't out of the box has that. But I would be glad to see a better answer!

Comment: You could put the call to get the ids of the exhibitors in a subquery to eliminate one query.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations to be able to create a query using a relationship without doing multiple calls

Comment: And then using joins?

Comment: What about something like this: http://pastie.org/10802207

Get the Event by ID, Expand the exhibitors and select only the dishes of those Exhibitors. This would lead to the following SQL query http://pastie.org/10802215

PS: This is pseudo code. I'm not talking about compiling Laravel code here.

Comment: Please post some real code, because this code doesn't work.

Comment: What about: http://pastie.org/10802261 (still pseudo code). ? this will get the Exhibitors who are linked to the specific event, and select all it's dishes on a SQL level.

Comment: You select dish columns from the exhibitor table? That wouldn't work.

Comment: No i'm telling ORM to include 'dishes'. Eloquent will inspect it's configuration and determine where to fetch those dishes from.